# Adhoc version bag

Tags: iphone, ios, adhoc

i have a problem with ad-hoc version of ios-app(in debug version there is no problem)
When i try to do next with twitter:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
```

i have a error thread1.
help,please)

Comment: can you post the error?.

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}   thread1

Comment: If the error is happening in main, what is the reason you think the presentModal... is the suspect?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
[self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
```

Calling `presentModalViewController` on NavigationController looks wrong to me.